# How to "melt" row wise instead of column wise in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, melt

I have a data frame `A` that I would like to melt row wise instead of column wise to look like `B` (which also excludes observations with `NA` in them). Can this be accomplished with the "melt" function?

```
A <- read.table(text="  Id1 Id2 Var1    Var2    Var3    
            1   1   1   2   NA  
            1   2   NA  3   4   
            1   3   5   6   7   ", header=T)


B <- read.table(text="  Id1 Id2 NewVar  
    1   1   1   
    1   1   2   
    1   2   3   
    1   2   4   
    1   3   5   
    1   3   6   
    1   3   7   ", header=T)
```

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169820/row-wise-manipulation-on-large-dataset) to a similar question but the function seems like overkill and is beyond my current R skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `order` it after `melt`ing

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(A), id.var = c("Id1", "Id2"), na.rm = TRUE, value.name = "NewVar"
     )[order(Id1, Id2)][, variable := NULL][]
#   Id1 Id2 NewVar
#1:   1   1     1
#2:   1   1     2
#3:   1   2     3
#4:   1   2     4
#5:   1   3     5
#6:   1   3     6
#7:   1   3     7
```

---

Or we can do with `base R` by replicating to expanding the rows of 'A' for the 'Id' columns, and `cbind` with the transpose of non-Id columns, concatenated.

```
`row.names<-`(na.omit(data.frame(A[rep(1:nrow(A), each =3), 1:2], 
                    NewVar= c(t(A[-(1:2)])))), NULL)
#  Id1 Id2 NewVar
#1   1   1      1
#2   1   1      2
#3   1   2      3
#4   1   2      4
#5   1   3      5
#6   1   3      6
#7   1   3      7
```

Comment: I don't understand, isnt this question just a basic reshape with minor formatting? `reshape(A, dir = 'long', varying = 3:5, sep = '')`

Answer (score 5):

From the tidyverse, melt -> summarise -> unnest

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyr)
melt(A, id=c("Id1", "Id2")) %>% group_by(Id1, Id2) %>%
  summarise(value=list(value[!is.na(value)])) %>% unnest()
# Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
# Groups: Id1 [1]
# 
#     Id1   Id2 value
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     1
# 2     1     1     2
# 3     1     2     3
# 4     1     2     4
# 5     1     3     5
# 6     1     3     6
# 7     1     3     7
```

**Edit**

Since `melt` has an `NA` removal argument (credit: @Frank) , a one-liner will do. Note: this line is a reshape2 version of akrun's data.table approach:

```
melt(A, id=c("Id1", "Id2"), na.rm=TRUE)[-3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr` with `gather` from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
A %>% gather(Key,NewVar,Var1:Var3) %>% 
      filter(!is.na(NewVar)) %>% 
      arrange(Id1,Id2) %>% select(-Key)
##  Id1 Id2 NewVar
##1   1   1      1
##2   1   1      2
##3   1   2      3
##4   1   2      4
##5   1   3      5
##6   1   3      6
##7   1   3      7
```

This will gather the columns `Var1:Var3` into rows in the `NewVar` column. The `Key` column will contain the names of the column that is gathered, which we don't need in the final result. After gathering, `filter` out the `NA` rows in `NewVar`. Then sort by `ID1` followed by `ID2` and remove the `Key` column.